# Get the highest value among user input prices?

Tags: java

I'm trying to code a program that:

Allows the input of the price of a product and its amount.
It must show the total price of the product. I'm thinking `price * quantity`.

That process has to repeated as many times as the user wants.

When the process finish it must print the value of the product more expensive, the total quantity of products sold, and the total value of all the products.

So far this is my code:

```
int value;
int quantity;
int total = 0;
int total_sold = 0;
int total_cashier = 0;
float expensier = Float.MAX_VALUE;
int again = 1;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );
System.out.println("Ingrese valor del producto: ");
value = input.nextInt();

Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System. in );
System.out.println("Ingrese cantidad: ");
quantity = input2.nextInt();

for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
    total += value * quantity;
    total_cashier += total;

    if (value > expensier) {
        expensier = value;
    }
}

total_sold = quantity;

System.out.println("Total to pay :" + total);
System.out.println("Value of the expensiest product: " + expensier);
System.out.println("Amount of products sold: " + total_sold);
System.out.println("Amount of cash in cashier: " + total_cashier);
```

Comment: at what part you are stuck?

Comment: for example how can I get the highest of the number and also how to make the user input as many value and quantity of a product.

Answer (score 1):

You are initialising expensier to the largest value java knows about.

This means the condition

```
if (value > expensier) {
```

will never happen, as value can never be bigger than MAX_VALUE.

Change it to `MIN_VALUE` instead.

However, there are other problems, you're mixing types (floats and ints), but otherwise that should get you going again.

Answer (score 0):

For the highest value, you are doing essentially the right thing, except that you are initializing the variable incorrectly

```
float expensier = Float.MAX_VALUE;
```

Is not what you want. You do not want a float (since all the values are ints) and you want to initialize it to zero because Float.MAX_VALUE is already the biggest value, so you will never find anything bigger.

try

```
int expensier = 0;
```

To input more than one value, wrap the whole thing from the first println to the end in a while loop.

Comment: but while under what condition? Also, Im having trouble getting the total value of cash in cashier.

Comment: @PBRD I would suggest a `while(true)` and then ask the user if they have more values and exit the loop if they do not. Can you say what problem you are having with the total_cashier

Comment: @PBRD also I see that you will have trouble with total_sold. You should be be using `+=` to accumulate the total, not `=`